# ffmpeg and codec utvideo interlaced

Tags: ffmpeg, video-codecs

i have ffmpeg version 2021-01-09-git-2e2891383e-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers.
Command : ffmpeg -h encoder=utvideo
gives :
gbrp gbrap yuv422p yuv420p yuv444p
I want yuv422. I see in forums it is possible. I don't know if it is possible with ffmpeg and with which (old?) version. Perhaps memcoder?
Best regards

Comment: Same thing with ffmpeg 4.4.

Comment: What is the question? I'm not quite sure what you want to do.

Comment: How to have UTVideo with yuv422 in ffmpeg ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to have UTVideo with yuv422 in ffmpeg ?

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v utvideo -vf format=yuv422p output.avi
```

Use the [format filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) (or the alias `-pix_fmt`) to choose the pixel format.

Comment: I don't want yuv422p ( progressive)

Comment: p means planar not progressive

Comment: see https://www.programmersought.com/article/57905707062/ "YUV422P is also a kind of YUV422. It is a Plane mode, that is, plane mode. It does not interleave the YUV data".

Comment: @jean-luc You must choose one of the pixel formats listed in `ffmpeg -h encoder=utvideo`. The FFmpeg implementation of this encoder does not offer packed YUV 4:2:2 (yuyv422, uyvy422, yvyu422) nor interleaved chroma.

Comment: Do you know tools with UTvideo packed YUV 4:2:2 (yuyv422, uyvy422, yvyu422)?